# Calculating limit

Tags: limits

I need confirmation for the following question.

> Which of the following statements is true?
>
> $1.$ $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{1/2}}=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}x=\infty$
>
> $2.$ $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{1/2}}=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}x=0$
>
> $3.$ $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{1/2}}=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}x=0$
>
> $4.$ $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{1/2}}=0$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}x$ does not exist.

So, I am thinking that however large $x$ be, $\log x$ will remain small. So, a small quantity over a very large one would give us $0$ as result. And sqrt of a large number is also a large number. So, answer should be $3).$

Am I correct here?

Comment: Well, except that $\log x$ will not remain small. It grows much slower than any power though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice is correct: $\log x$ grows more slowly than any positive power of $x$. It’s not true that $\log x$ remains small, though. You can make it as large as you want: assuming that this is the natural log, $\log e^x=x$. The $0$ limits are easily verified using l’Hospital’s rule, if you’re familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

As $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty^+}\frac{\ln x}{x^n}$ is of the form $\frac\infty\infty$ for $n>0$

Applying L'Hospital's Rule

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty^+}\frac{\ln x}{x^n}=\lim_{x\to\infty^+}\frac1x \cdot\frac1{nx^{n-1}}=\frac1n\cdot\frac1{\lim_{x\to\infty^+}x^n}=0$ if $n>0$

Comment: log is not defined for -ve values, so it must be $\infty^+$. But why specifically for non-integers? I would assume it should be so for every n.

Comment: @Ramit, thanks for the observation. Rectified